# Axioms for constructability

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory

When we are doing geometric constructions we assume that the only operations we can perform are

1. We can draw a line between to points.
2. We can draw a circle with one point as the centre and the other pooint as the radius.

In this case we can prove that operations like trisecting an angle are not possible. But I have seen constructions which involve operations like marking a line segment of length one and sliding it to trisect an angle as in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection#With_a_marked_ruler). So I am just curious to know if there are some more generalised systems available where we can allow even these operations. If anyone has any references or ideas about this it would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Arthur Baragar, Constructions using a compass and twice-notched straightedge, Amer. Math. Monthly, 109 (2), 151 - 164 (2002). There's a link to it at Arthur's website, https://faculty.unlv.edu/baragar/ (click on Research, go to paper 13).